# Microsoft JWT token validation

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt

I receive a JWT token (ID token) how do I validate it correctly? As I understand it, Microsoft uses an asynchronous signature for the JWT token, so I have two questions: Where can I get the public key for verification? And secondly, how can I use it for verification?

P.S. why does google have an official token validation library, but microsoft does not?

I need to verify tokenId token received from MS Azure AD
The token itself, I get on the Angular client, which is then sent to the server, where it must be verified.
Below is an example of code that displays tokenId to the console.

```
export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private tokenService: TokenStorageService, private readonly _authService: SocialAuthService) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._authService.authState.subscribe(this.externalAccountLogin);
  }

  signInWithMicrosoft(){
    this._authService.signIn(MicrosoftLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
  }

  externalAccountLogin(user: SocialUser): void{
    switch(user.provider){
      case MicrosoftLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID:
        console.log(user.idToken);
        break;
      case GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID:
        //ToDo
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why would every vendor need their own JWT validation library? It's a standard so if a validation library is built once, it should work for every JWT.

Comment: Are you expecting to validate a JWT provided by MS Azure AD Open Id ? Could you please share the way you get this token so we can understand which OpenId flow you're using and then help you

Comment: @Evert I'm sorry, it was more of a rhetorical question) I just really liked how Google checks the token validation: 


GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload payload = GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(idToken, settings).Result;

And I hoped that the check for Microsoft would be done in a similar way, but as a result, I can’t figure out how to do it.

Comment: *asynchronous signature* - you probably mean asymmetric signature algorithm, eg. RS256.

Comment: @CyrilANDRE Yes, you are right, I added to the question, the code by which I receive the tokenID

Comment: @jps Yes, that's right. I meant it

Comment: don't know what your _authService.signIn does. Do you have tenant_id, clientId, eventually scope and a secret ? 
Can you share the signIn method ?

Comment: @CyrilANDRE __auth Service is a service from the @abacritt/angularx-social-login package. When calling the "signIn" method, it does all the work on its own, displays a window in which the user authenticates using his Microsft account. After that, information about the user is returned to externalAccountLogin method using callBack. Including idToken. Here this token is simply output to the console, but normally it should be sent to the server, where it should be authenticated.

Comment: @CyrilANDRE I definitely have a ClientID since I use it in the @abacritt/angularx-social-login package. Perhaps I have other data, for sure they are in the Microsoft Active Directory control panel

Comment: I found this article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/884100/azure-ad-access-token-validation.html
explaining you can get the keys from Azure
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<<<tenant_id>>>/discovery/v2.0/keys
Then if you decode your token, you'll find the kid to be used to search the correct key.
Does it help ? Or do you need more input ?

Answer (score 0):

> why does google have an official token validation library, but microsoft does not?

Have you try microsoft.identity.web package.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/microsoft-identity-web

I could authenticate my API with it.

Answer (score -1):

It is very common and there are lot of articles to implement this. Please find the below

[JWT Implementation in Asp.Net Core](https://codepedia.info/jwt-authentication-in-aspnet-core-web-api-token)

[JWT Token Implementation .Net 6.0](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-implement-jwt-authentication-in-web-api-using-net-6-0-asp-net-core/)

[Creation of JWT Token .Net](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/jwt-json-web-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/)

Microsoft also has library to validate jwt token.

**How JWT Validate Token**

There are three major part in tokens :- Token Type & Algo, Payload and Last one Signature.

When you add Jwt Configuartion in your applicationof .Net Core then

1. Validate Token

   First it check that signature is correct or not. if someone tamper the
   signature then throw exception for token is not valid.

`For this we provide validation parameter such as key, issuer and audience in TokenValidationParameters`

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
    {
        x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
        var Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:Key"]);
        o.SaveToken = true;
        o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Key)
        };
    });
```

2. Need to valid payload or claim

   We can create middleware to validate payload or claim. And Validate by fetching data from payload and create logic validate that.

**Validate JWT Token of Azure AD**

A. Can Use Microsoft Graph API to validate that.

1. [Enable ASP.NET Core web app to sign in users and call Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/?source=recommendations)
2. [Protect Aspnet Core Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/?source=recommendations)

B. OR Follow the same Steps which mentioned above by using `TokenValidationParameters`. Key, issuer and audience are  also available in JWT TokenId of Azure AD. Get from azure portal and copy in startup in `TokenValidationParameters`.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not much of what I need. You see, I just need to check the token and get the subject field from it. Then, based on this information, I will already create my own JWT token.

And your example apparently uses a symmetric key, but here it should use an asymmetric one.

Comment: I got your question and trying to find out solution. In one of my project. we are using same scenario. we are getting token from Azure AD and use Microsoft graph Api to validate that.

Comment: Can this [Link](https://dev.to/eduardstefanescu/jwt-authentication-with-asymmetric-encryption-using-certificates-in-asp-net-core-2o7e#:~:text=The%20idea%20behind%20using%20asymmetric,it%20with%20the%20public%20key.) help you ?

Comment: public key can be got from azure